# Por qué no coincide el cuerpo de la tabla con la opción lengthMenu seleccionada?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, datatable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Me sucede cuando relleno una tabla con Ajax con una función que va fuera de la inicialización de la DataTable. (Edito la pregunta agregando más información).

Cuando cambio a cualquiera de las demás opciones que ofrece lenghtMenu de DataTables esta no me muestra la cantidad de filas que corresponde según lo que selecciono, a alguien más le ha pasado? cómo se puede solucionar?

Comment: ... Hola, bienvenido a stack overflow en Espanol. Tu pregunta es muy difícil de responder porque no nos da la información suficiente para responderla. Tampoco nos das detalles del error o la duda del problema y mucho menos nos das el código para ver qué está mal. Te aconsejo que edites la pregunta para que podamos ayudarte y te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: en lo personal no uso datatables de esa forma... y cada vez que la uso en realidad la destruyo y la inicializo nuevamente para evitar este tipo deproblemas...